# php trying to echo to view and stop script if alert

Tags: php, mysql

For my register script I want to be able to alert the user if a name is already taken and other things like that. However if I return the object to be used then the script stops I can't call the view()

For Example my site is boostrapped so everything runs through index. Index instantiates APP and calls init(). init turns my url into useful things like a controller a method and parameters and calls them. like site.com/controller/method/param1/param2

```
class App
{
    protected $controller = '';

    protected $method = 'index';

    protected $params = [];

    public function init()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
            $url = explode('/', filter_var(trim($_GET['url'], '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
        else
        {
            header('Location:/home');
        }

        if (file_exists(CONTROLLER . $url[0] . '.php')) 
        {
            $this->controller = $url[0];
            unset($url[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            if (DEVELOPMENT == true) 
            {
                exit(var_dump($url));
            }
            else
            {
                header('Location:/home');
            }
        }

        require_once CONTROLLER . $this->controller . '.php';

        $this->controller = new $this->controller;

        if (isset($url[1])) 
        {
            if (method_exists($this->controller, $url[1])) 
            {
                $this->method = $url[1];
                unset($url[1]);
            }
        }

        $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];

        call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->method], $this->params);
    }

    public function view($view, $data = '')
    {
        require_once VIEW . 'header.htm';
        require_once VIEW . $view . '.htm';
        require_once VIEW . 'footer.htm';
    }
}
```

So when I visit site.com/user/register my register method is called automatically.

If I add return $this->alert then I stop the script and the view never gets called so I kill the view and dont echo the alert.

If I don't return $this->alert then I can pass the $this->alert to the view as a parameter but I can't stop the script from running and it inserts a user even though an alert has been issued.

```
class User extends App
{

    public $alert;

    public function register()
    {                    
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
        {
            $username = trim($_POST['username']);
            $usernameActual = strtoupper($username);
            $email = trim($_POST['email']);
            $password = trim($_POST['password']);
            $passwordConfirm = trim($_POST['passwordConfirm']);

            if (stripos($username, ' ')) 
            {
                $this->alert = '<div class="notice"><p>Usernames cannot contain spaces.</p></div>';
            }
            else
            {
                foreach ($results as $r) 
                {
                    if ($usernameActual == $r['usernameActual']) 
                    {
                        $this->alert = '<div class="notice"><p>Sorry. The username you entered is already registered with us.</p></div>';
                        // $return $this->alert;
                    }
                    if ($email == $r['email']) 
                    {
                        $this->alert = '<div class="notice"><p>Sorry. The email you entered is already registered with us.</p></div>';
                        // $return $this->alert;
                    }
                }
                if (strlen($password) < 8 || strlen($password) > 20 || preg_match("/[0-9]/", $password) === 0 || preg_match("/[A-Z]/", $password) === 0) 
                {
                    $this->alert = '<div class="notice"><p>Passwords must meet the following criteria:</p><ul><li>Must be more than 8 characters.</li><li>Must be less than 20 characters.</li><li>Must contain at least 1 number.</li><li>Must contain at least 1 upper case letter.</li></ul></div>';
                    // $return $this->alert;
                }
                else 
                {
                    if ($password === $passwordConfirm) 
                    {
                        $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));
                        $insert = $this->con->db->prepare('INSERT INTO users (username, usernameActual, email, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)');
                        $insert->bind_param('ssss', $username, $usernameActual, $email, $hashedPassword);
                        if ($insert->execute()) 
                        {
                            echo 'inserted';
                            // $this->sendActivationEmail();
                        }
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        $this->alert = '<div class="notice"><p>The passwords you entered did not match.</p></div>';
                        // $return $this->alert;
                    }              
                }
            }
        }

        $this->view('user-register', ['alert' => $this->alert]);
    }
}
```

this is the view

```
<?php if (isset($data['alert'])) { echo $data['alert']; } ?>
     <form action="/user/register" method="post">
         <input type="text"  name="username" placeholder="Username" required class="form-control">
         <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required class="form-control">
         <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required class="form-control">
         <input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" placeholder="Confirm Your Password" required class="form-control">
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
     </form>
```

How can I stop the script inserting the user if there is an alert and still get my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can throw exceptions.  Exceptions cause the code to stop executing and jump into the first catch where they can be dealt with.  They have to be wrapped in try{} catch (Exception $e){} blocks but these blocks can be several layers up in the call stack.   The important part is throw stops the execution at that line so you're insert will never happen.

```
class User extends App
{

    public $alert;

    public function register()
    {                    
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
        {
            try{
                $username = trim($_POST['username']);
                $usernameActual = strtoupper($username);
                $email = trim($_POST['email']);
                $password = trim($_POST['password']);
                $passwordConfirm = trim($_POST['passwordConfirm']);

                if (stripos($username, ' ')) 
                {
                    //$this->alert = '<div class="notice"><p></p></div>';
                    throw new Exception("Usernames cannot contain spaces.");
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach ($results as $r) 
                    {
                        if ($usernameActual == $r['usernameActual']) 
                        {
                            //$this->alert = '<div class="notice"><p>Sorry. The username you entered is already registered with us.</p></div>';
                            // $return $this->alert;
                            throw new Exception( "Sorry. The username you entered is already registered with us." );
                        }
                        if ($email == $r['email']) 
                        {
                            // $this->alert = '<div class="notice"><p>Sorry. The email you entered is already registered with us.</p></div>';
                            // $return $this->alert;
                            throw new Exception("Sorry. The email you entered is already registered with us.");
                        }
                    }
                    if (strlen($password) < 8 || strlen($password) > 20 || preg_match("/[0-9]/", $password) === 0 || preg_match("/[A-Z]/", $password) === 0) 
                    {
                        // $this->alert = '<div class="notice"><p>Passwords must meet the following criteria:</p><ul><li>Must be more than 8 characters.</li><li>Must be less than 20 characters.</li><li>Must contain at least 1 number.</li><li>Must contain at least 1 upper case letter.</li></ul></div>';
                        // $return $this->alert;

                        // NOTE: I don't recoment embedding html in your exception messages. 
                        throw new Exception("Passwords must meet the following criteria:</p><ul><li>Must be more than 8 characters.</li><li>Must be less than 20 characters.</li><li>Must contain at least 1 number.</li><li>Must contain at least 1 upper case letter.</li></ul>");
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        if ($password === $passwordConfirm) 
                        {
                            $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));
                            $insert = $this->con->db->prepare('INSERT INTO users (username, usernameActual, email, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)');
                            $insert->bind_param('ssss', $username, $usernameActual, $email, $hashedPassword);
                            if ($insert->execute()) 
                            {
                                echo 'inserted';
                                // $this->sendActivationEmail();
                            } 
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            // $this->alert = '<div class="notice"><p>The passwords you entered did not match.</p></div>';
                            // $return $this->alert;
                            throw new Exception( "The passwords you entered did not match." ); 
                        }              
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception $e ){
                $this->alert = '<div class="notice"><p>' . $e->getMessage() .'</p></div>';
            }
        }

        $this->view('user-register', ['alert' => $this->alert]);
    }

}
```

This is my recommended approach.  Validate will check the username for errors and if found throws an exception.  The exception isn't caught in the validate method so it will pop out of the validate method and be caught by the try-catch in the register method.

```
class AlternateUser extends App
{
    public $alert;

    public function register()
    {                    
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
        {
            try
            {
                $this->validate();

                $username = trim($_POST['username']);
                $usernameActual = strtoupper($username);
                $email = trim($_POST['email']);
                $password = trim($_POST['password']);
                $passwordConfirm = trim($_POST['passwordConfirm']);

                $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));
                $insert = $this->con->db->prepare('INSERT INTO users (username, usernameActual, email, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)');
                $insert->bind_param('ssss', $username, $usernameActual, $email, $hashedPassword);
                if ($insert->execute()) 
                {
                    echo 'inserted';
                    // $this->sendActivationEmail();
                } 

            } catch (Exception $e ){
                $this->alert = '<div class="notice"><p>' . $e->getMessage() .'</p></div>';
            }
        }

        $this->view('user-register', ['alert' => $this->alert]);
    }

    private function validate()
    {

        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        $usernameActual = strtoupper($username);
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
        $passwordConfirm = trim($_POST['passwordConfirm']);

        if (stripos($username, ' ')) 
        {
            //$this->alert = '<div class="notice"><p></p></div>';
            throw new Exception("Usernames cannot contain spaces.");
        }

        foreach ($results as $r) 
        {
            if ($usernameActual == $r['usernameActual']) 
            {
                throw new Exception( "Sorry. The username you entered is already registered with us." );
            }

            if ($email == $r['email']) 
            {
                throw new Exception("Sorry. The email you entered is already registered with us.");
            }
        }

        if (strlen($password) < 8 || strlen($password) > 20 || preg_match("/[0-9]/", $password) === 0 || preg_match("/[A-Z]/", $password) === 0) 
        {
            // NOTE: I don't recoment embedding html in your exception messages. 
            throw new Exception("Passwords must meet the following criteria:</p><ul><li>Must be more than 8 characters.</li><li>Must be less than 20 characters.</li><li>Must contain at least 1 number.</li><li>Must contain at least 1 upper case letter.</li></ul>");
        }

        if ($password !== $passwordConfirm) {
            throw new Exception( "The passwords you entered did not match." ); 
        }
    }
}
```